# Will IP layer split TCP segments?

Tags: tcp

I know that data from the application layer is split into segments by the Transport Layer (like TCP). Also, the Data Link layer might split the datagrams into multiple frames.

What about the Internet layer? Will IP layer simply encapsulate the segment or will it further split it?

Thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 0):

The IP layer can't split a single TCP packet into multiple TCP packets, because it doesn't know what TCP is. However, routers along the network path may choose to fragment the IP packet itself into multiple pieces. Each of those pieces contains only a fraction of the TCP packet, so they all need to be received before the TCP layer can go to work. (For that matter, the sending machine can send out the packet pre-fragmented if it likes, though one generally tries to size the TCP packet so it doesn't have to.)

All that's the theory. In practice, IP fragmentation is uncommon, and avoided as much as possible. Additionally, IPv6 doesn't support fragmentation at all.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself? The reason routers can split IP packets is because they don't know or care what they are, surely the same can apply to TCP and IP. The IP layer can split a TCP packet across multiple IP packets, then reassemble them at the destination?

Comment: @ollie299792458 The point is, the fragments of a TCP packet are not themselves TCP packets. In contrast, the fragments of an IP packet *are* themselves IP packets.